# Dismiss back to rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have imported a third party library into my project which I am presenting in the appDelegate (using deep links).  The view presents fine, but when it comes to removing this library ViewController it doesn't work.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

appbarViewController = [[AppBarViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = appbarViewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];   
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if([[url host] isEqualToString:@"session"]){

   ACSViewController *acs = [[ACSViewController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:[acs view]];
  [window.rootViewController presentViewController:acs animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Then from within the Library ViewController class I am calling

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

I have tried various ways to dismiss, popToRoot, but I am not returning to my original viewController. Is the way I am presenting the library ViewController in the appDelegate removing my root from the stack?

Comment: I think you need to remove `[window addSubview:[acs view]];`. Its unnecessary and this is visible after dismissing the acs viewcontroller.

Comment: i didn't need that, it still does the same, the ACSViewController animates away but then returns, like it is the only ViewController in the stack and is reloading it?

Comment: I don't see anything that would change your root view controller.  Immediately after doing the "dismiss", it would be interesting to see what your root controller is.  Something like: `NSLog(@"Root controller: %@", [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController]);`

Comment: When dismiss and log the root view, the rootView is appbarViewController.  Does that seem ok? The library ACSViewController only gets called at the point above so I don't understand why it won't return to it?

Comment: ACSViewController is a separate library with its own navigationController.  Might have something to do with it?